# DevExpress RibbonControl MVVM (WPF .NET)

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm, devexpress

I have recently started to work with MVVM and DevExpress RibbonControl.
My idea is to create a MasterView (MainView) with its RibbonControl, and at RibbonPage swap call the correct View (V_Product or V_Client) which bind the correct ViewModel (VM_Product or VM_Client). [I have create an UML diagram to explain my idea.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ho0o8.png)

To do this I have encountered some problems:

1. When switch to another view, a new view object has been created. To avoid data loss I declare static a lot of class fields.
2. To avoid point 1, I have encapsulated many data fields into VM_Main but it became too big and I lose class separation advantage.
3. I create many Pages to render detail views, is it correct or is better to use UserControls? To switch pages I have used Frame (Navigate method) but I don't like this solution. I found an example where has been used ContentPresenter binded to UserControl object.

Is RibbonControl suitable for MVVM implementation?
Command binding in VM_Main can become too complicated if I have a lot of detail views.

Waiting for any advice.

Regards, Andrea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's suitable for MVVM and there'is also a sample on Devexpress website:
[Check the links on the right](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E20019)